# Password screen still gives access when null

Tags: null, passwords, ms-access-2013

My password screen still gives access when user name matches but the password is left blank.
How do I add it so it rejects with the password left blank?

```vb
Private Sub btnLogin_Click()

    Dim rs As Recordset
    
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("EmpPW", dbOpenSnapshot, dbReadOnly)
    
    rs.FindFirst "Username='" & Me.txtUserName & "'"
    
    If rs.NoMatch = True Then
        Me.lblWrongUser.Visible = True
        Me.txtUserName.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Me.lblWrongUser.Visible = False
    
    If rs!password <> Me.txtPassword Then
        Me.lblWrongPass.Visible = True
        Me.txtPassword.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Me.lblWrongPass.Visible = False
    DoCmd.OpenForm "employee_form"
    DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name

End Sub
```

Comment: When `Me.txtPassword` is Null, your condition (`rs!password <> Me.txtPassword`) does not evaluate as True.  Instead, it evaluates as Null. So none of the code in that block is run, and the final 3 instructions in that procedure (which include the `OpenForm`) do run.

Comment: You can use [Nz()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/nz-function-8ef85549-cc9c-438b-860a-7fd9f4c69b6c) to transform the Null into something else for the purpose of that comparison: `rs!password <> Nz(Me.txtPassword, "")`